# Usage of pointer in C programming

Tags: c, pointers

I am encountering a difficulty in trying to understand the usage of pointers in C programming. I do not understand why this doesn't compile:

```
void func(char**p);
void other_fun(void)
{
    char arr[5][3];
    func(arr);
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  You need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: What is `func`? You only show a declaration.

Comment: `arr` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: The rule is that an "N-element array of `T`" decays to a "pointer to `T`"; `arr` has type "5-element array of 3-element array of `char`", so in this case `T` is "3-element array of `char`".  Thus, `arr` decays from `char [5][3]` to `char (*)[3]`.  So your `func` prototype needs to be `void func( char (*arr)[3] )`.

Answer (score 3):

The major issue is that arrays are **not** the same as pointers. Syntactically, you can use them in a very similar manner within a function, but they are not the same. As such, what you are passing in `func(arr)` is a variable of type `char (*)[3]`, or a pointer to an array of 3 `char`s, and not a pointer to a pointer, which is what `func` expects.